Is AWS-SDK Timestream WriteRecords already supported by Step Function (eu-central-1)?
Hey AWS team, I was integrating a AWS SDK call from my step function in order to write some records on a timestream table. Here is the SFN definition :
"WriteRecords": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Next": "Success",
      "Parameters": {
        "DatabaseName": "TimestreamDatabase",
        "Records": [
          {}
        ],
        "TableName": "ChainTableTimestream"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:timestreamwrite:writeRecords"
    },

Unfortunately, I ran into a problem at execution : An error occurred while executing the state 'WriteRecords' (entered at the event id #7). The resource provided in the resource ARN is currently not supported.
Good to know : my step function has describeEndpoints and writeRecords permissions. I know my records array is empty but it does not matter cause the problem might not come from Timestream API but prior the call (SFN strange behavior).
According to your documentation, you have just added Timestream Write support on January 2024. I don't know what I missed exactly.
I've tried the timestream query step as well. I encountered the same error.
Instead of generating with CDK, I updated the step function manually, basically the same behavior. It crashes in another region too.
